# deploy asp.net, IIS no import application option

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm trying to deploy my ASP.net webpage on my local using IIS base on the steps from this site http://www.shubho.net/2011/01/quick-deployment-of-aspnet-applications.html

However, when I'm trying to do an import application, the option wasn't available. I tried reinstalling MSDeploy, but it still didn't work.

Any one had an idea of how to set my application importing?

Comment: I've seen the same problem on a Windows 7 laptop and a Windows 8 laptop. On my Windows Server VM, the option works as expected.

Comment: You already mentioned it, but still did you verify that you have this component installed correctly http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy and working state (sometime restart would also help after installation)

Comment: In addition to SubhashDike 's comment above, make sure that you are working with an ASP.Net Web Application project, and not an ASP.Net Website. You will get different results with the Website.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do to publish to local is Click the publish and create "New". Then when asked in the wizard instead of Web Deploy select "File System", then in the target location browse to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\YourFileName. Make sure VS is in Release Mode to publish. In IIS 7 you will set up a new site and make sure you set the Directory to the same file location. Then you're done.